# Place the divs next to each other

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to change the following code:

```
<div class="col-lg-8" ng-repeat="contact in [{name:'Jim'},{name:'Joe'},{name:'Dan'}]">
        <div class="col-lg-3">   
            <div>{{contact.name}}</div>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

as to ***get the names next to each other*** and not vertically as it is the case now?

Comment: `div` is a block element.  Block elements line up column-wise.  The next question(s) that follow are:  do you really want a block element, or do you want to use flexbox for this?

Comment: `float:left` is your friend

Comment: Actually, instead of names I have divs which contain some information about each customer. I want to fit as many as possible in a lg-8 size and at the same time this one to be responsible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your current html code will repeat `<div class="col-lg-8">` three times. You probably want to change it to following:

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4" ng-repeat="contact in [{name:'Jim'},{name:'Joe'},{name:'Dan'}]">
            <div>{{contact.name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will produce three `<div class="col-lg-4">` to be fit in `<div class="col-lg-9">`.

Comment: That would still be incorrect bootstrap code. A .col-xxx must be inside a .row. Otherwise, the spacing and margins is all wrong.

Comment: Of course. I am assuming OP has a wrapper element with `class="row"` before this code.

Comment: Your answer places a .col-lg-3 directly inside a .col-lg-9, so it doesn't respect the bootstrap rules. Why should the OP and all other readers assume that a .row should be added to the code in your answer? Why not fix the code instead?